# When you run the code, why does the bottom of the graph start with 2003 and then 2013 and then it starts back from 1 again

Tags: python, pygal

```
`import pygal


the_data = [["Firefox", [None, None, 0, 16.6,   25,   31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1]],
        ["Chrome",  [None, None, None, None, None, None,    0,  3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3]],
        ["IE",      [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5,   66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1]],
        ["Others",  [14.2, 15.4, 15.3,  8.9,    9, 10.4,  8.9,  5.8,  6.7,  6.8,  7.5]]]



chart = pygal.StackedLine(fill=True)
chart.title = "The browsers usage"
chart.x_labels = map(str, (2002, 2013))


for label, data_points in the_data:
    chart.add(label, data_points)


chart.render()
```

`
what is the problem because the code looks correct please help because this is a schools project

Comment: What's wrong with the code's output?

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a mistake in this line:

```
chart.x_labels = map(str, (2002, 2013))
```

basically `map(str, (2002, 2013))` creates a collection with only two values `["2002", "2013"]` and because you have more columns the library fills it with other numbers (1,2,3), what you want is to have the list of all the years:

```
chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
```

check the **range** function, this will generate the collection with `['2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012']`